Numa different allocations
We have a physical server with Ubuntu 22.04 OS. The default numa policy is 'local'. As far as I know, 'local' policy should stick only one numa node. In this scenario, memory being mapped across all nodes. Can you please let know why 'local alloc' spanned multi numa nodes. TIA.
077cf000 default file=/usr/local/apache/httpd anon=2 dirty=2 active=0 N1=2 kernelpagesize_kB=4
077d1000 default file=/usr/local/apache/httpd anon=67 dirty=192 mapmax=3 active=124 N0=125 N1=67 kernelpagesize_kB=4
079ed000 default anon=1617 dirty=1617 active=0 N0=920 N1=697 kernelpagesize_kB=4
09e82000 default heap anon=44 dirty=44 active=0 N1=44 kernelpagesize_kB=4```


- The first entry shows memory allocated on N0 node with default.
- The second entry shows memory allocated on N1 node with default.
- The third entry shows memory allocated both on N0 abd N1 with default.

